# Glass Mapper v4 InferType Cast issue

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

I can't understand why Glass Mapper can't cast object in correct way like described [here](http://www.glass.lu/mapper/sc/tutorials/tutorial17)
I have next classes

```
 public class BC
    {
        [SitecoreId]
        public virtual ID Id { get; set; }        
    }

public class WB : BC
    {
        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "P1")]
        public virtual Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link P1 { get; set; }
    }

 [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{XXX}", AutoMap = true, EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
    public class AAA : WB 
    {
        public virtual string AAAP1 { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime AAAP2 { get; set; }
    }
 [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{VVV}", AutoMap = true, EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
public class BBB : WB 
    {
        public virtual string BBBp1 { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime BBBp2 { get; set; }
    }

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{YYY}", AutoMap = true)]
    public class RazorRenderClass: BC
    {                      
        [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
        public virtual IEnumerable<WB> Children { get; set; }

        [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
        public virtual IEnumerable<AAA> AAACh { get; set; }

        [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
        public virtual IEnumerable<BBB> BBBCh { get; set; }
    }
```

at razor view I can't get AAA or BBB objects if I use Children  property,

```
 @foreach (var child in Model.Children)
    {
        if (child is BBB)
        {
            var news = child as BBB;
            <li>
                11
            </li>
        }
        else if (child is AAA)
        {
            var evt = child as AAA;
            <li>
               222
            </li>
        }
    }
```

What is more interesting, if I use call to BBBCh or AAACh properties at cshtml, I can see(at debug) that Children property contains correct items (object) but if I try to get any item from Children property like

```
  var detailWidget = Model.Children.FirstOrDefault();
```

it would cast to WB class.
What I can do with it ?

Comment: Hey.. this may have been resolved with a newer version of Glass. What version are you using?

Comment: There was a bug with Glass v4, which may be what you're seeing. It was fixed with release 4.0.1.5 - https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/132

Comment: I saw about this version issue but my version is 4.0.1.8

Comment: Do you have your assembly registered in the GlassLoaders in the GlassMapperScCustom.cs ?

Comment: If you are using Attribute Configuration or automapping/on-demand mapping you don't need to do anything! it is comment from glass mapper

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde Still can you try that ? :)

Comment: What should try ? I installed galas mapper from nuget and this comment from code

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde In your GlassMapperScCustom.cs GlassLoaders method add the following -  return new IConfigurationLoader[]{ new AttributeConfigurationLoader("[YOUR ASSEMBLY NAME"), };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the exact same problem, with version 4.0.5.54.

My hack around solution was to specify the subtypes as properties like you did with AAACh and BBBch. But setting up without lazy loading them.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{YYY}", AutoMap = true)]
public class RazorRenderClass: BC
{                      
    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true, IsLazy = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<WB> Children { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true, IsLazy = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AAA> AAACh { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true, IsLazy = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<BBB> BBBCh { get; set; }
}
```

I really don't like that I have to specify, AAACh and BBBch as property. In glassmapper v3 the following would have sufficed.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{YYY}", AutoMap = true)]
public class RazorRenderClass: BC
{                      
    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<WB> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also had this issue. Adding this to GlassMapperScCustom's GlassLoaders method fixed it for me:

```
return new IConfigurationLoader[]{ new AttributeConfigurationLoader("MyAssembly")};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the configuration loaders only fixed it intermittently for me. Basically, anytime the w3wp would cycle, some types would be correct and some would be Castle Proxies.

I think it's a bug in the latest version.

My workaround is rebinding it myself with code:

```
protected List<ORM.IBaseModule> LocalModules;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var contextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        var service = new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database.Name);

        LocalModules = new List<ORM.IBaseModule>();
        foreach (Item child in contextItem.Children)
        {
            if (child.TemplateID == ORM.AAAConstraints.TemplateId)
            {
                LocalModules.Add(service.Cast<ORM.AAA>(child));

            }
            //repeat for each type of child
         }
```